# Add CSS Class to Row Elements If Value Equals

Tags: html, jquery

Using JQuery I would like to check the value of an input, if it equals `Complete` I would like to add the Bootstrap class `is-valid` to that input, and all the other inputs on the same row.

Something like this (pseudo code);

```
if wb_status_reg = Complete {
   // add is-valid to all row inputs / select boxes
}
```

I should note that sometimes the row will contain a select box, not just text inputs. Also, I'm unable to edit the html as it's being generated by a form builder component (in a CMS).

My code is currently working but I know it's too long and could be improved. In my code i'm showing one `form-row` but I actually have many more, so I need to duplicate this a few more times.

How can I achieve this in a more efficient way?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var wb_stage_reg = $('#wb_stage_reg');
  var wb_status_reg = $('#wb_status_reg');
  var wb_date_reg = $('#wb_date_reg');
  setIsValid($);
});

function setIsValid($) {
  wb_stage_reg = ($(wb_status_reg).val().trim() == "Complete") ? $(wb_stage_reg).addClass("is-valid") : "";
  wb_status_reg = ($(wb_status_reg).val().trim() == "Complete") ? $(wb_status_reg).addClass("is-valid") : "";
  wb_date_reg = ($(wb_status_reg).val().trim() == "Complete") ? $(wb_date_reg).addClass("is-valid") : "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="form-group rsform-block-wb-stage-reg">
      <div class="formControls">
        <div class="sp-input-wrap">
          <input class="form-control" id="wb_stage_reg" name="form[wb_stage_reg]" type="text" value="Registration"><span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="form-group rsform-block-wb-status-reg">
      <div class="formControls">
        <div class="sp-input-wrap">
          <input class="form-control" id="wb_status_reg" name="form[wb_status_reg]" type="text" value="Complete"><span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="form-group rsform-block-wb-date-reg">
      <div class="formControls">
        <div class="sp-input-wrap">
          <input class="form-control" id="wb_date_reg" name="form[wb_date_reg]" type="text" value="2020-06-08 09:41:40"><span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

You need to change ID to class on all fields

Since you cannot, I use the name instead:

```js
$(function() {
  $("[name='form[wb_status_reg]']").each(function() {
    const $parent = $(this).closest(".form-row");
    const complete = this.value === "Complete";
    $parent.find("[name='form[wb_date_reg]'], [name='form[wb_stage_reg]']").toggleClass("is-valid",complete)
  })  
});
```

```css
.is-valid { color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="form-group rsform-block-wb-stage-reg">
      <div class="formControls">
        <div class="sp-input-wrap">
          <input class="form-control wb_stage_reg" name="form[wb_stage_reg]" type="text" value="Registration"><span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="form-group rsform-block-wb-status-reg">
      <div class="formControls">
        <div class="sp-input-wrap">
          <input class="form-control wb_status_reg" name="form[wb_status_reg]" type="text" value="Complete"><span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="form-group rsform-block-wb-date-reg">
      <div class="formControls">
        <div class="sp-input-wrap">
          <input class="form-control wb_date_reg" name="form[wb_date_reg]" type="text" value="2020-06-08 09:41:40"><span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @mplungjan, apologies I should have mentioned that I can't edit the html as it's being generated by a form builder component (in Joomla). So this doesn't work. I'll update my original question.

Comment: Then it is generating invalid HTML ID must be unique. So change the selector

Comment: You can use removeClass and addClass if you want to differentiate between is-valid and is-warning